# Does me vs Does for me

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

> - “I want to kill the queen myself, for all the good it does me,” the younger one said.
>
> Is not supposed the preposition ***For*** to come after does: to be like all the good it does me?

Comment: No preposition is needed. "Me" is the _indirect object_ of _do_ in this sentence. See also _"Give me a break"_.

Answer (score 1):

Like @P. E. Dant said,  "Me" is the *indirect object* of *do* in this sentence. Indirect objects do not necessarily need prepositions in situations like these.

Take this sentence from [this article:](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/grammar/direct-and-indirect-objects/)

> Samuel sent his aunt a postcard from Martha’s Vineyard.

From the article:

*“Samuel” is the subject, and “sent” is the verb. Ask the question “sent what?” “A postcard” is the **direct object**. To determine the i**ndirect object**, ask who received the direct object. “His aunt” is the indirect object.*

You **could** write the sentence as:

> Samuel sent a postcard **to** his aunt from Martha's Vineyard.

But this is mostly a matter of preference, as both of these sentences mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this scenario: a person wants to hear a very popular band, and in order to get tickets, shows up at the ticket window at midnight the day before.  But there is already a long line of fans there ahead of him.  The person might say:

> I came here eight hours early—*for all the good it did me*!

The meaning is that the person did not really get much benefit from coming early. "For all the good it did me" is an exclamation.

With respect to the indirect object:

> Try this home-made brandy. It will do your cough some good.

There, **your cough** receives the benefit.

Comment: Let's call it a dative instead.

Comment: Bestimmmmmmmmt.

Comment: No matter how I try to say this in German, it comes out as _Your cough will do something good to it._ To hell with it. I'm giving up now and moving to Tok Pisin: _"i fixim onepela cofcof"_.